# insert end linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

I am having problem in inserting data at the end of the linked list. I have tried everything but no help. It is only showing first and the last no but the numbers in between.

Following is my code.

```
struct node
{
  int data;

  struct node *next;

} *start;

add()  
{

    int a,b,c=0;
    scanf("%d",&a);

    struct node *new,*new1;
    new=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    new1=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    while(a!=0)
    {
        c=a%10;
        a=a/10;
        if(start==NULL)
        {
            new->data=c;
            start=new;
            printf("%d\n",start->data);

        }
        else
        {
            new1->data=c;
            new->next=new1;
            new=new->next;

        }
    }
    new->next=NULL;
}
```

Comment: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/08/c-linked-list-example/

Comment: `add() ` --> `void add()`

Comment: How do you insert nodes? Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Ravi: It's a very good idea to separate out the acquisition of user input and the insertion into the linked list.

Comment: Also, learn to use a debugger and step through the code line by line, it will help you enourmously.

Comment: Your code is reusing the same 2 list nodes to build the entire list, so in the end you'll only ever see 2 entries. "new" will be the first element you see, and "new1" would be the last. You want to allocate a new node in each loop iteration and keep appending to your list inside the loop.

Comment: There are multiple issues with your code. Best if you find a working example and study that. But for starters, in your `else` case, the new node is never chained to `start`. And you should never need to malloc two nodes for a single addition.

Comment: 1) in C, do not cast the returned value from mallco() (and family of functions)  2) always check (!=NULL) the returned value from malloc() to assure the operation was successful.   3) The initial declaration of the struct pointer needs to be set to NULL, so an append operation does not think that some nodes have already been allocated.  4) there is no/zero need to allocated more than one instance of the struct to perform an append operation.  5) 'new' is a C++ keyword. If using a C++ capable compiler, the code will fail at execution time if not at compile time.

Comment: it seems that (given the posted code) that the function is expected to append 1 or more allocated instances of the struct.  I.E. if the user entered 25, there would be one (or more) instances of structs with the data set to 5,  in any case, the 'start' pointer should only be modified once.  From then on, the code needs to loop through the linked list until is finds a allocated struct with the 'next' field = NULL and append any new struct(s)

Comment: this question needs some clarification on exactly what is expected to occur when any (suggest using examples) value is entered by the user.  It would be a very good idea to prompt the user for the value, so the user is not left looking at a 'blank' screen with an input prompt and no clue as to what to enter.

Comment: suggest only one 'malloc()' and placing that malloc inside the loop

Answer (score 0):

you are re-writing 2nd node every-time. move to the last of linked list and then add

```
add()  
{

int a,b,c=0;
scanf("%d",&a);

struct node *new,*new1;
while(a!=0)
{
    c=a%10;
    a=a/10;

    new=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    if(start==NULL)
    {
        new->data=c;
        new->next = NULL;
        start=new;
        printf("%d\n",new->data);

    }
    else
    {
        new1=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        new1 = start;
        while(new1->next != NULL) {
            new1 = new1->next;
        }
        new->data=c;
        new->next = NULL;
        printf("%d\n",new->data);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Although i dint compile it. Run this code and it should work. Let me know

Comment: the else is still buggered.  new1 is assigned twice.

Comment: aah. my mistake. dint see that. thanks for pointing that out. tested it on a compiler. works great.

Comment: might want to update your answer so cut/paste will work for others...  :)

Answer (score 0):

```
void print(struct node *p){
    while(p){
        printf("%d\n", p->data);
        p = p->next;
    }
}

void add(void){
    int a;
    scanf("%d", &a);

    struct node *new, *curr;
    for( ;a!=0; a /= 10){
        new = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        new->data = a % 10;
        new->next = NULL;

        if(start==NULL)
            start = curr = new;
        else
            curr = curr->next = new;
    }
    print(start);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. The problem was that I was using the same new1 again and again. When the satisfying case appears it should be always allocated memory. The modified code is as below:-

int a,b,c=0;

```
scanf("%d",&a);
while(a!=0)
{
    struct node *new,*new1;
    c=a%10;
    a=a/10;
    if(start==NULL)
    {
        new=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        new->data=c;
        start=new;
        printf("%d\n",start->data);
    }
    else
    {
        new1=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        new1->data=c;
        new->next=new1;
        printf("%d\n",new->next->data);
        new=new->next;
        new->next=NULL;
    }
}
```